# How to write a simple series in python?

Tags: python, series

I'm new to python and have been given this task - I need to find the sum of a series but I haven't found any help online. Any help would be greatly appreciated - thank you.

[image: Image of the task]

Comment: Please give more examples of your need, also add what you got by now.

Answer (score -1):

```
numbers = [10,22,33, 54 ] # we declare a list of numbers
import numpy as np  # we import the library "numpy" and we name it 'np',
```

#### it offers lot of matrix calculations

```
np.array(numbers).sum() # here we declace a numpy array and we applicate the sum function
```

or

```
sum(numbers) # this is a simple exemple of using 'sum' function with a simple array
```

## numpy arrays are so fast in calculations that's why we use it

import numpy as np
    def squared(X):
        y = np.array(X)**2
        return y

Comment: Please add a few sentences to explain what your code is doing, so you can get more upvotes for your answer.

Comment: def squared(X):
    return sum(i*i for i in numbers)

Answer (score -1):

```
def squared(numbers):
    return sum(i*i for i in numbers)
```